# Find K s.t. $\int_{\Omega}|K-f(x)|(K-f(x))=0$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let $\Omega$ a bounded set of $\mathbb{R}$, $f\in L^3(\Omega)$.
Find $K\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

$\int_{\Omega}|K-f(x)|(K-f(x))=0.$

I'dont know how to begin.
My first idea was to split the integral where $K-f(x)$ is lower or greater then 0 but in this way I couldn't conclude anything. Any help?

Comment: Try to think about $x \mapsto \int |x -f(y)|^3\,dy$.

Comment: But in this way u have a function everywhere posivitive. How can be zero?

Comment: Find a minimizer of the function I wrote. Calculate the derivative.

Comment: ok now I understand your idea but in my opinion it's very difficult to find that minimum.

Comment: Youn only need to show existence. Or do you want to explicitly calculate $K$?

Comment: I want to explocitly calculate K. I have alredy proved the exiatence.